# How to read a text file in blocks to return specific lines

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, struct, line

I need to be able to read a text file in line by line and get the contents of the line when it starts with a certain text, however it may not always be there, which gives me null return and affects my datagridview.

I want to make a method that will read the data in blocks when it sees the first line (source: always there) and read in the other lines, and if that line does not exist then set the variable associated to it as " ".

For example the text file will be

source: C:\
MRU: 1
MRU time: 12/12/2013

source: C:\
MRU: 2
MRU time: 13/12/2013

source: C:\
MRU time: 12/10/2013
//notice no MRU

Here is the code I am using to get the line if it contains the string:

```
 String line = file.ReadLine();
 if (line.StartsWith("source"))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText((line) + Environment.NewLine);        
        }

        if (line.Contains("MRU"))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText((line) + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        if (line.Contains("MRU time"))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText((line) + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is the result you get from the above code? To begin with, if looks like you're doing all your processing only on lines that begin with "source", but you have up to 3 possible separate lines, right? So you'd want 3 if statements, if (line.StartsWith("source")), else if (line.Contains("MRU time")) and else if (line.Contains("MRU")). Note you'd want them in that order if you need to distinguish between lines with MRU time and just MRU.

Comment: Basically I need to read the data in 'blocks', where the first line will always begin with source, and end with a space between the next block. So I made if statements to find the source, however this runs across all lines, rather than that inside of the 'blocks'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a console app that does exactly what you need. Just alter it to fit your needs. Your main problem was you didn't have a null check. This is also wrapped up in smaller functions so it's a bit cleaner(at least to me)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadFile();
    }

    private static void ReadFile()
    {
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\bharrison\Desktop\test.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Reading file");
        while (!SR.EndOfStream)
        {
           string ReturnedValue = AnalyzeString(SR.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine(ReturnedValue);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string AnalyzeString(string line)
    {
        string TempLine = line;

        if (TempLine != null && TempLine != "")
        {

            if (TempLine.Contains("source"))
            {
                return TempLine;
            }

            if (TempLine.Contains("MRU"))
            {
                return TempLine;
            }

            if (TempLine.Contains("MRU Time"))
            {
                return TempLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return " ";
        }
        return " ";
    }
```